# Error:Access denied creating App_Data subdirectory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have created Simple MVC 3 Application . For Login the application uses ASPNETDB.mdf which is by default. When I access it from my computer the application works fine , but when I deploy it on IIS I am getting error

`Access denied creating App_Data subdirectory`

My web.Config is as follows

```
         <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

It's because the user this app is running under does not have permission to add new folders on IIS.  When you don't have any contents under App_Data folder visual studio won't deploy it. So, you could add a placeholder.txt file in your App_Data folder and redeploy it, then it should work fine.

Comment: Can you provide some links